# Getting CURLE_COULDNT_CONNECT error when using URL which return JSON Outupt

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

I want to read a Webpage and get Data using LibCurl Library in C++. When I am using URL which return JSON Output then it is giving me CURLE_COULDNT_CONNECT.

```
#include <curl/curl.h> 

size_t Read_WebPage(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream) 
{ 

    int numbytes = size*nmemb; 
    // The data is not null-terminated, so get the last character, and replace 
    // it with '\0'. 
    char lastchar = *((char *) ptr + numbytes - 1); 
    *((char *) ptr + numbytes - 1) = '\0'; 
    contents.append((char *)ptr); 
    contents.append(1,lastchar); 
    *((char *) ptr + numbytes - 1) = lastchar;  // Might not be necessary. 
    return size*nmemb; 
} 

int main()
{
  curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    CURL* curl = curl_easy_init(); 
    if(curl) 
        { 
        // Tell libcurl the URL 
        curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php");  // Return JSON OutPut (NOT WORKING)

    // Tell libcurl what function to call when it has data 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION,Read_WebPage); 
        // Don't wait forever, time out after 10 seconds.
        //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        // Do it! 
        CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curl); 
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl); 
    }

    return 0     
}
```

Comment: Can you try setting `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);` and `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_STDERR, stderr);`?

Comment: curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php"); 
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_STDERR, stderr);
// Tell libcurl what function to call when it has data 
 curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION,Read_WebPage); 
    
CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curl); 
     
     // On this curl_easy_perform Line i got Exception error in Visual Studio C++ project.
     In Dialogbox it was giving me "Unhandled exception at 0x7745eb83 in DemoCurl.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000014."

Comment: After adding your code, curl_easy_perform Line i got Exception error in Visual Studio C++ project. In Dialogbox it was giving me "Unhandled exception at 0x7745eb83 in DemoCurl.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000014."

Comment: I have added only CURLOPT_VERBOSE, then it is giving like below                                                                                                                   *   Trying 93.184.220.20...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* connect to 93.184.220.20 port 80 failed: Timed out
* Failed to connect to www.w3schools.com port 80: Timed out
* Closing connection 0

Comment: TCP fails to establish a connection to the IP, there's something in your network/setup/system that makes curl not work.